# Why image upload to django rest framework endpoint returns 0 NO RESPONSE?

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework

I have created endpoint in Django Rest Framework and I want that only authenticated users can create and change data. Im using Token Authentication.

When I try to update profile_picture of Testik instance (via PATCH method) providing right credential. (Authorization = Token xxxxxxxxxxxxx), it works, profile_picture is updated and status code 200 is returned.

But whenever credentials are wrong or missing, it doesnt return error 401 (Unauthorized) which I see in django terminal output: "PATCH /api/testik/1 HTTP/1.1" 401 59" but I get "Status
0 NO RESPONSE"

So I have this model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Testik(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, db_index=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/testik',blank=True)
```

with associated serializer:

```
from models import Testik
from rest_framework import serializers

class TestikSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Testik
        fields = ('url', 'profile_picture','first_name')
```

and this ViewSet:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from serializers import TestikSerializer
from models import Testik
from rest_framework import mixins,permissions,viewsets,parsers

# Create your views here.

class TestikViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    serializer_class = (TestikSerializer)
    queryset = Testik.objects.filter()
    parser_classes = (parsers.MultiPartParser,parsers.JSONParser)
```

Does anyone have an indea what I did wrong or what http request (maybe specific Content type / I tried multipart or something) should I use please?

Answer (score 0):

For file uploads you need to use the `multipart/form-data` content type.

---

Additionally the `PATCH` verb won't typically support file uploads. You'll need to use a `PUT` (replace) or `POST` (create) to handle that.

Comment: Content-type is set to multipart/form-data and PUT behave the same way, its probably something else

Comment: Where is that `0 NO RESPONSE` found? Our findings are that `PATCH` is supported oddly in a browser especially when mixing file uploads. I would also make sure to specifically list `profile_picture` as a file field in the `TestikSerializer`.

Comment: Im using postman app to test my restapis, now it just says: "Could not get any response
This seems to be like an error connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/testik/1. The response status was 0.
Check out the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec for more details about when this happens." 

but I can see in terminal output that django raise error 401.

I think profile_picture field is set right, because when I provide correct authorization credential, profile_picture is correctly saved.

Comment: It's entirely possible that something in the middle of that stack is interfering with the response and dropping it before it gets to postman.

Comment: Try using something like [httpie](http://httpie.org) and dumping full headers with `-p HhBb`.

Comment: Well I tried httpie and it behave even weirder, because sometimes I get the right response and sometimes it returns error: [Errno 10053]. I read about this error and it really looks like something at level of OS or firewall is terminating the connection :(